# Limits using definite integration

Tags: integration, limits, functions

$F(k)$ = $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{1^k + 2^k +...+n^k}{(1^2 + 2^2 +...+n^2)*(1^3 + 2^3 +...+n^3)}} $$
I need help in finding $F(5)$ and $F(6)$.
I tried converting it into summation form and using the progression formulas of $n^2$ and $n^3$ but it was of no use.

Comment: For any positive integer $k$ the sum $1^k + 2^k + \dots + n^k$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$.

You can find the sums in this [link](http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/power.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem:** Define $S_r(n)=1^r+2^2+...+n^r$, $$\frac{n^{r+1}}{r+1}\leq S_r(n)\leq\frac{(n+1)^{r+1}}{r+1}$$ for any positive $r\geq0$

Then $$\frac{12n^{k+1}}{(k+1)(n+1)^3(n+1)^4}\leq{\frac{1^k + 2^k +...+n^k}{(1^2 + 2^2 +...+n^2)\cdot(1^3 + 2^3 +...+n^3)}}\leq \frac{12(n+1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)n^3n^4}$$

So, $$F(6)=\frac{12}{7}$$ and $F(k)=0$, if  $0\leq k<6$ and $F(k)=+\infty$, if $k>6$

Comment: And the theorem is easily proved by integral $$0^r+1^r+...+(n-1)^r\leq\int_0^{n}x^r d x\leq 1^r+...+n^r$$

Answer (score 1):

You only need the largest terms in the fraction, the rest converge to 0. What are the leading constants in $\sum_{j=1}^{n} k^5, \sum_{j=1}^{n} k^2, \sum_{j=1}^{n} k^3$?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the sums:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n i^5= \frac{n^2(n+1)^2(2n^2 + 2n - 1)}{12}\\$$

Comment: How did you find the value of $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^5 $$

Comment: @exilednick I found it here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28i%5E5%29+for+i+from+1+to+n But you can also find it by knowing that the result must be a sixth degree polynomial then solving a couple of equations...